# Connect elixir livebook to running phoenix application

Tags: deployment, elixir, phoenix-framework

## Why I want to do it?

- Allow all business logic functions to be available to the data scientists

## Environment

- Nginx as reverse proxy
- Phoenix application (without docker, `mix release` and systemd)
- Livebook

All running on a VPS (Ubuntu)

## What I did so far

Got livebook to run with the following command
`LIVEBOOK_IP=<IP> LIVEBOOK_PORT=8089 LIVEBOOK_PASSWORD=<PASS> LIVEBOOK_COOKIE=<COOKIE> livebook server --name livebook@127.0.0.1`
It is accessible in the browser via IP and Port.

Running the phoenix application `mix release` with the environment variables

```yaml
      RELEASE_COOKIE: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_COOKIE }}
      RELEASE_DISTRIBUTION: name (literally)
      RELEASE_NAME: <appname>
      RELEASE_NODE: <appname>@<PUBLIC_IP>
```

I try running livebook without docker on the same machine to make absolutely sure that they are able to connect, but no luck so far.

## What doesn't work

Connecting to the phoenix application from a livebook does neither work from a locally installed livebook nor from the one deployed on the server.
The screenshot tutorials I'm following are here: [fly.io link](https://fly.io/docs/elixir/advanced-guides/connect-livebook-to-your-app/#getting-the-node-name)
It says that the node is not reachable.
[image: error message]

Comment: Make sure erlang cookies are the same.

Comment: Any way how I can check them? I'm sure that the one I set in `RELEASE_COOKIE` is the same as `LIVEBOOK_COOKIE`.

Comment: Googling showed me `:erlang.get_cookie`. There is also a file called `COOKIE` in each released version.

The problem now seems to be that my name is not set properly anymore. I'm on it, even though it's just setting my name to staging no matter what I do. `Hostname staging is illegal`

Comment: Unbelievable. Somehow mnesia was using that old hostname. We use that to persist pow user sessions. That cost me half a day.

Answer (score 5):

So a couple of things to note if anyone else runs into something similar. I got it to work and it's pretty awesome.

The elixir apps are started with `--name app@ip_or_domain`. `ip_or_domain` needs to have dots. Alternatively using a short name `--sname app` does also work, but is not recommended and somehow turns off access from another machine.

These arguments (`--sname` etc.) are influenced by the [mix release environment variables](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.14.3/Mix.Tasks.Release.html#module-environment-variables). So setting the variables before invoking `mix release` or inside `env.sh` and `env.bat` is the way to go. Namely:

- `RELEASE_DISTRIBUTION=name`
- `RELEASE_NODE=myapp@staging.myapp.com` (DNS resolution or IP)
- `RELEASE_NAME=myapp`
- `RELEASE_COOKIE="cookie"`

For debugging I was just manipulating `vm.args`, but you should rather be using these mix release env variables.

For livebook I set up the following in `/etc/myapp/livebook.conf`:

```
LIVEBOOK_IP=195.XXX.XXX.XXX
LIVEBOOK_PORT=8089
LIVEBOOK_PASSWORD="password"
LIVEBOOK_COOKIE="cookie"
```

Setting up a daemon was surprisingly easy. You should probably make sure this does not run in the root folder and as root though.

`/etc/systemd/system/livebook.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Livebook server for myapp app
After=network.target
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
EnvironmentFile=/etc/myapp/livebook.conf
EnvironmentHome=/root

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'PATH=/root/.asdf/shims:$PATH exec livebook server --name livebook@127.0.0.1'

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

`systemctl enable livebook.service` and
`systemctl start livebook.service`

The livebook app is then accessible under `LIVEBOOK_IP:8089` and can attach to the runtime. All application code is available, autocompletion works too, collaborative editing etc.

I hope this helps someone with a similar idea. Feel free to adapt, edit and clarify this answer.
[image]

By the way, I can actually use a locally installed livebook to connect to the app now. But it kills the other livebook connection, so only one livebook can be connected at one point.

Comment: You should be able to connect as many notebooks as you want, assuming they have different node names.

Comment: I often have 10 or so LiveBooks v0.81 open, some of them on genservers running code periodically.  They are all connected to a phoenix app on my local machine using the SAME node name (I use phoenix for some google api calls where a localhost address is needed).   I'm interested in this 'kills the connection' issue.  Does anyone know if I would I have problems connecting 10 Livebooks to a remotely hosted phoenix app? many thanks!